# Tomcat dependency in a project that is a dependency for a project that also uses tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, dependencies

I have project-A that is has Tomcat as a dependency and acts as a library for web applications that I write. I have project-B that is a web application that has tomcat as a dependency as well as project-A as a dependency. When I deploy project-B as a web app and run it with Tomcat I get a NoClassDefFoundError:javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.

I am guessing this is because project-B is has two references to the Tomcat library? What is the best way to structure dependencies like this? I have tried to use Maven (for the first time) with this project to help solve this, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Do I need to setup Tomcat as a Maven dependency in both projects and exclude it in the pom for Project-B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has this issue I'll outline how I solved this. In my project-B I had inadvertently added the project folder for project-B to the build time classpath. In eclipse this is under the run configuration settings for the tomcat server in this case. A odd issue that I accidentally caused myself but it might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you kept project-A classes? Looks like you have not included project-A as  dependency to  project-B.. Have you kept project-A jar or classes in Web application of project-B.. 
Or you may need to put your project-A jar inside tomcat classpath itself. Moreover, you may not need to include all dependency in project-A jar, skip tomcat jar to avoid redundancy..

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Project-a is a compiled jar that includes the tomcat jar. I can't not include tomcat because then project-A will not compile. This jar is then placed in the lib folder for Project-B.

Comment: why are you packaging tomcat JARs in your project-A JAR? Simply package your classes and place under project-B lib. I believe it should work.

Comment: If I don't include tomcat in project-A then when compiling to a jar it has compile errors because it can't source tomcat. If I then try to use this jar within project-b it still fails.